# JSON root element

Tags: xml, json

Does JSON require a root element as in XML case. As far as I know this is a valid JSON string.

```
{
    "email":[
        {
            "type":"home",
            "name":"john.doe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "type":"work",
            "name":"jdoe@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to convert JSON to XML an vice versa. However although the above is valid JSON when I convert it to XML it is not valid? Am I missing something or this is normal?

Comment: What library are you using for the conversion and what error is it showing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The outermost level of a JSON document is either an "object" (curly braces) or an "array" (square brackets).

Any software that converts JSON to XML has to reconcile the fact that they are different data models with different rules. Different conversion tools handle these differences in different ways.

**UPDATE (2021-09-03):** As noted in the comments, subsequent iterations on the JSON specification allow the outermost level to be a string, number, boolean, or null.

Comment: Do you have a canonical reference for this? I cant validate that anywhere. It appears that any properly formatted element (array, object, string, number, etc) is technically a valid JSON root element, though the first two are the only ones which can have children.

Comment: Actually there are two different JSON specifications. RFC 4627 requires a JSON text to be an object or an array. ECMA-262, 5th edition, section 15.12 does not impose this restriction.

Comment: It seems that [RFC 7159, section 2 "JSON Grammar"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-2) has removed this restriction and now allows any value as the "root".

Comment: Unfortunately it was the spec at json.org that caused this problem in the first place, by failing to say which constructs in the grammar were permitted as the top-level production. Short specs are good (see also XPath 1.0) but often leave ambiguities that have to be sorted out later.

Answer (score 17):

According to the modified Backus-Naur-Form on the right side pane of http://json.org/ the root element of a JSON data structure can be **any** of these seven types/values:

```
Object
Array
String
Number
true
false
null
```

#### Examples

So all of the following examples are valid JSON root elements:

```
{
  "name": "Jpsy",
  "age": 99
}
```

```
[ 1, 2, "three", 4, 5 ]
```

```
"abcdefg"
```

```
123.45
```

```
true
```

```
false
```

```
null
```

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, json and xml don't have the same rules. You can transfrom your root brackets "{" and "}" into a root element to be sure to don't have conversion problems