# How to parse JSON with unknown key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I'm using POST with AFNetworking to receive and send data from a server. In one of the cases I'm getting the next JSON:

```
{
    20 = "Some text";
    25 = "some other text";
}
```

The content of the JSON is unknown, I only know that there will be a number equals some text. 
Usually I use valueForKey but in the above I don't know what the key is going to be. 
How can I parse the above into any array separating the id and the text?

Thanks

Comment: Once you convert it into `NSDictionary` you can retrieve the keys from the `allKeys` method.

Comment: A number is not a valid key in an JSON Object. The keys have to be JSON Strings. Hint: when you print out JSON in order to illustrate the matter, please log it as _JSON_ - not just printing a NSDictionary's content, via NSLog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find keys list from the dictionary using  below code further you can do by using keys.

```
NSArray *keys = [yourdict allKeys];
```

Answer (score 1):

convert it to a dictionary like this:

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:*yourJSONObject* options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

and then get the keys with the method the others here already mentioned

```
[dataDictionary allKeys];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the JSON you're referring to is a dictionary type.

i.e.

```
{
    20 : "Some text",
    25 : "some other text"
}
```

If this is the case then once it is converted to an object...

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourJSONData options:0 error:nil];
```

You can then get all the keys from it...

```
NSArray *allTheKeys = [jsonObject allKeys];
```

You can then iterate the key array to get the values for each.

Comment: it JSON Data directly can be use as the formate it has say NSDictionary. data he has is already JSON not NSData.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? FFS! a down vote and your explanation is complete gibberish?!

Comment: He has JSON data already that we can directly use as Dictionary. in JSONObjectWithData: method we need NSData as a parameter. so we can use JSON data as Dictionary than why to create NSData and then Dictionary. that's what I meant.

Comment: There is nothing in the question to say that. Plus, my answer also gives the same answer as above and in the comment but of which haven't been down voted. `NSArray *allTheKeys = [jsonObject allKeys];` I would assume as a programmer that if he already had the `NSDictionary`, which I doubt, that he would be able to see which part is relevant to him.

Comment: clearly mentioned in the ques that he is getting JSON data but he is not sure about JSON content.

Comment: Yes JSON "data". JSON data is just NSData. There is no difference. What you receive from an NSURLConnection is NSData. This may or may not be JSON data. It doesn't mean that it isn't NSData. Nowhere in the question does it mention "object" or "NSDictionary" or even "dictionary". I think you need to read up on how JSON works.

Comment: So this JSON, we can use directly as NSDictionary.

Comment: No. JSON is not an NSDictionary. JSON is a way of representing an NSDictionary (or other objects). Jeez, just remove your down vote and admit it was wrong.

Comment: @suraj you obviously have no clue what you're talking about here. You can read more about JSON here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON please tell me where it says that JSON can be used as an NSDictionary.

Comment: thank you for your advise but I don't need to read anything about JSON, you just do one thing, run my code (my answer code) with any JSON data and see it will work so smooth, I didn't mean JSON is exactly same as NSDictionary but what I mean is, we can use it as NSDictionary as I used in my Answer. Please see my answer.

Comment: Your answer only work if the `JSON` variable is an `NSDictionary` (or at least `id`). You can only get an `NSDictionary` from JSON data by running the code in my answer. You need to convert between JSON and an actual Objective-C object.

Comment: can you show me a single JSON data that is not in key value pair??

Comment: Oh FFS, here you go... `[
    1,
    2,
    3
]` this is a valid JSON array. You can test it here... http://jsoneditoronline.org . Also, this `"Hello"` is a valid JSON string.

Comment: ha ha ha...this is an array I agree but this array you added correspond to "array" key.same you added "boolean", "number","string" keys and data correspond to these keys.
this is again key value pair dear. I asked you any JSON with out key-value pair??? I can use this also as NSDictionary and my code will work this for sure.

Comment: I guess you didn't do what I suggested which is to test the array string on it's own in that website. Seriously, you're in over your head here. Now go call under a rock and stay quiet.

Comment: I can also tell you something same or more worse but I won't; go and enjoy, have a good day...

Comment: @suraj please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426924/json-root-element especially the answer, "The outermost level of a JSON document is either an "object" (curly braces) or an "array" (square brackets)." Like I said many times, you are wrong. The more you argue with that the more you are just showing your ignorance. It goes further to say that the JSON root element can be an object, array, or any valid JSON type.

Answer (score -1):

try out this say you JSON data is in JSONData variable

```
if([JSON isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSDictionary * dictionaryFromJSON = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
    for(id key in [dict allKeys])
    {
        id obj = [dictionaryFromJSON objectForKey:key];
        // use this obj & key as you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the `JSON` variable is actually an `NSDictionary` (or at least `id` received from `NSJSONSerialization`). If you get data from an NSURLConnection and try to run this it will break. First you need to convert the NSData received by the connection into an Objective-C object (like an NSDictionary or an NSArray). Only once this is done will this work. However, this still doesn't exaplin why my answer is so bad as to down vote it.

Comment: @Fogmeister you are right,now please just think in context of this question, with AFNetworking framework he is getting JSON data and i.e.
{
    20 = "Some text";
    25 = "some other text";
}

now please think & tell me, will that code work or not ??

Comment: Yes, BUT ONLY IF IT HAS BEEN CONVERTED FROM DATA TO AN ACTUAL OBJECT LIKE A DICTIONARY! This is what I have been saying repeatedly but you refuse to accept that you are wrong. What you have put in your comment is neither JSON data nor an NSDictionary. It is a string that (incorrectly) represents the JSON representation of a dictionary.