# Can a single, stand-alone literal form a valid JSON "document"?

Tags: json, validation, specifications, lint

For example, is this supposed to be a valid JSON document?

```
"foo"
```

The grammar specs at json.org isn't entirely clear. I don't think it is said anywhere in the specs that everything must be in a `{}` object or `[]` array in a valid JSON document.

JSONLint marks the stand-alone string `"foo"` as an error and expects everything to be inside a `{}` object or a `[]` array.

However, the JSON object of major browsers (IE 8, IE 10, Chrome 28, Firefox 23, Opera 12) accept stand-alone literals just fine:

```
>>> JSON.parse('"foo"');
"foo"
>>> JSON.parse('true');
true
>>> JSON.parse('1234');
1234
```

Same thing with Python 2.7+:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"foo"')
u'foo'
>>> json.loads('true')
True
>>> json.loads('1234')
1234
```

So who is right and who is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this on comment

> Actually there are two different JSON specifications. RFC 4627 requires a JSON text to be an object or an array. ECMA-262, 5th edition, section 15.12 does not impose this restriction.

[JSON root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426924/json-root-element)

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt is a copy of RFC 4627 and defines a JSON text as a serialized object or array at the beginning of section 2.  In practice, though, like the OP I find that singleton texts are also usually acceptable to parsers.

Comment: Personally, I prefer ECMA-262's take. I believe it makes the most sense for a JSON text to be parsable into _anything_ that is assignable (object, array, string, boolean, number)  to a single variable.

Comment: RFC 4627 has since been made obsolete by [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-2), which explicitly allows a JSON text to be any of the available types.